# Where does pipenv install packages?

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm using vscode, and my editor shows:

[image]

The red is showing that it can't import those packages. I'm using a `pipenv` virtual environment and for the life of me, I can't figure out where it installs the packages.

If I could, I could just add that to `$PYTHONPATH` and life would be better.

Any help?

Comment: That would be the wrong solution. Instead you need to tell your editor about your virtual environment.

Comment: Wow - that was so much simpler. Worked like a charm. Can you post as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: `pipenv` stores all the virtual environments it creates in one place, which is a hidden directory in your home directory by default. I don't recall what its name is, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Daniel Roseman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846532/where-does-pipenv-install-packages#comment96465817_54846532), all I needed to do what tell `vscode` about the virtual environment created by `pipenv`

Comment: And how did you do that?

Comment: @Daniel you can do that by selecting the python interpreter from pipenv for that project. ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Answer (score 54):

pipenv installs packages in `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/`

To find the complete path, you can run `pipenv --venv`

The easiest way to load this into VS Code is to:

1. open the command palette `CTRL + SHIFT + P`
2. search for `Python: Select Interpreter`
3. Select the option indicated by `PipEnv`

[image]

[Full documented steps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Answer (score 5):

On windows machines start pipenv `pipenv shell` then `where python` to get the path to your scripts

Comment: Or `which python` on linux/mac.

Answer (score 2):

I spent like 2 hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong (the files would run but the imports would not resolve). Turns out it's surprisingly simple.

Go to the root of your project & open up a new terminal. Use the following commands to open a shell and get the location of the virtual environment.

```
>>> pipenv shell
>>> pipenv --venv

C:\Users\gasma\.virtualenvs\dungeon-generator-MV179gUf
```

If you open up this in the file explorer, you'll find exactly where the modules are being installed.

[image: where tf are these modules]

From here, you can create a new `.vscode/settings.json` file (still in your project directory) to let VS Code know what's up.

In my case, I typed this in:

```json
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:/Users/gasma/.virtualenvs/dungeon-generator-MV179gUf/Lib/site-packages"],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["C:/Users/gasma/.virtualenvs/dungeon-generator-MV179gUf/Lib/site-packages"]
}
```

Make sure your replace the file paths with the one you got from running `pipenv --venv`. To run your project, just use `python <file>.py`, and to exit the virtual environment, simply type `exit`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Complementing the answer, I am using ubuntu, so my config is:

`{
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT-2EVEaJZy/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
  ],
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT-2EVEaJZy/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
  ]
}`

Answer (score -3):

/Users//.local/share/virtualenvs//lib/python3.9/site-packages

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27926498)

Comment: It should be ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/your_python_venv/python3.9/site-packages